# Issue with Unity Rule Tiles not displaying the correct result

Tags: unity-game-engine, tile

Apologies up front if this question is badly asked or if I'm doing something very obviously idiotic...

My Unity project is dynamically dropping Rule Tiles onto a tilemap grid, using code similar to the below:

```
graphicalTileMap.SetTile(new Vector3Int(tempX, tempY, tempY), trackTile);
```

This works fine, but the Rule Tiles are not showing the correct tiles in place when I make the rules complicated.

This is an example of the Rule Tiles in action:

Image of simple Rule Tiles working

[image]

The path doesn't work properly, but that's fine because the rules are being followed in order and they are too simplistic to work properly.

However, when I make the rules more complicated:

Image of Rule Tiles not working

[image]

...they just default to the default sprite.

Note, each 'tile' is made up of 2x2 Rule Tiles, like so:

Closeup of tile map

[image]

I'm probably doing something very obvious wrong, but it's driving me mad! Any thoughts?

Comment: Well but in your second example of rules you limit the tiles to 3 directions .. which is not more complicated but simply something totally different. You tell it to only use the tiles if there is way in 3 directions which according to your image is probably never the case. Sounds to me like none of the conditions is met so it simply picks the last option as fallback

Comment: Hi! Ah, but remember the tiles are being used as 2x2 (see my last image), so surely the 3 directional rules would be met? 
Unless I'm missing something, which is perfectly possible.

Comment: Was just a guess tbh ^^ never worked with these tiles yet but that's the difference between them so it might be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if anyone else is ever likely to see this issue because it really was my own stupidity, but I fixed it. It turns out that the Z axis is also important when considering tiles; I modified my line of code that places each tile to read as follows:

```
graphicalTileMap.SetTile(new Vector3Int(tempX, tempY, 0), trackTile);
```

Problem solved and all my rule tiles now work as intended!